# Is it possible to take content of link after installing from app store?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io

I have one "referCode" in the branch link as parameter, And i don't the application installed in iOS device so it will take to AppStore and i will install the application. But after that if i open the application without clicking the link then would i be getting the param "referCode"? 
I would be able to get if i click the link, but what would happen in the above case. The above case is possible for android but what for iOS? 
I have tried the case with installed app and works totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: whenever a user opens a Branch link for your app on their device, all the data parameters from that link are tied to that device. The next time your app opens (within the timeout period, which is two hours by default but can be configured), all of those data parameters are always available for you to use. This is true regardless of the situation, including all of the following:

1. App opens *immediately* because the app is already installed
2. App opens fairly quickly because the user installs it and then opens right away
3. App opens some time later (perhaps the user downloads it, forgets, and then comes back after an hour).

That's the magic of Branch! It literally makes no difference...you still always get the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply